# c# webrequest hangs

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a project, which call a web address many times

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.GetResponse();
```

Here is my code. It is in a loop, it work for 2 times but on third iteration it hangs. There is no crash or error. Kindly please help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Error : After 20 min wait.

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
Message=The operation has timed out
Source=System
StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\WorkSpace\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 48
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

InnerException:

Comment: Did you close the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try  the following:

```
var response = request.GetResponse();
//do stuff with response
response.Close();
```

The `WebResponse` instance holds the active connection, and you have to close that connection before establishing new ones to the same server.

You could also do this with a `using` clause, it's really up to you:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    //do stuff with response
}
```

Comment: Thanks that saved me - my C# program was locking up eventually because I wasn't closing response per you above!